# How can I store data derived from Firebase, converted to an UIImage, to an UIImage array?

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am trying to retrieve pictures saved from the database (in this case I hard coded the exact picture I want from the database). I have two `UIImage` variables initiated: `imageView` and `rawImage`. imageView is using `SDWebImage` from `FirebaseUI` to load the image, but I don't know how to save it into a UIImage array.

rawImage is grabbing the data from the path of the exact image from Firebase. I am converting it to a UIImage but when I want to append it to my UIImage array, the application crashes.

```
class GalleryViewController:UIViewController{
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var rawImage: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addVerticalGradientLayer(topColor: primaryColor, bottomColor: secondaryColor)
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
        retrievePicture()
    }

    func retrievePicture()
    {
        guard let user_email = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email else { return }
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference()

        // Reference to an image file in Firebase Storage
        let reference = storageRef.child("\(user_email)").child("/top").child("1.jpg")

        // UIImageView in your ViewController
        let imageView: UIImageView = self.imageView

        // Placeholder image
        let placeholderImage = UIImage(named: "placeholder.jpg")
        //UploadViewController.Clothing.top_images.append(<#UIImage#>)

        // Load the image using SDWebImage
        imageView.sd_setImage(with: reference, placeholderImage: placeholderImage)


        // this is the code for the rawImage portion I described above
        reference.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error \(error)")
            } else {
                let picture = UIImage(data: data!)
                UploadViewController.Clothing.top_images.append(picture!)
            }
        }

        // loading the image to the rawImage imageview
            rawImage.image = UploadViewController.Clothing.top_images[0]

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already load the images using **SDWebImage** then you can also append the image in your **UIImage** array with that.

Just use **SDWebImage** with a completed block like this

```
var arr_image = [UIImage]()

imageView.sd_setImage(with: reference_url, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.jpg"), options: options: [.highPriority]) { (img, error, cachtype, url) in
    if img != nil{
        arr_image.append(img) // append UIimage in array 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have overlooked force unwrapping optionals, and I propose to you to remove `!` usage to avoid crashes, use following instead

```
reference.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
    guard let data = data else {
        print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Check remote url or service")
        return
    }

    if let picture = UIImage(data: data) {
        UploadViewController.Clothing.top_images.append(picture)
    } else {
        print("Invalid image data\n\(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))")
    }
}
```

or following if statement is safe

```
if error == nil && data != nil, let picture = UIImage(data: data!) {
    UploadViewController.Clothing.top_images.append(picture)
}
```

You can also try path without leading slash, like so:

```
let reference = storageRef.child("\(user_email)/top/1.jpg")
```